# (JavaScript) How to split a paragraph string into lines without - str.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, formatting, format

My program is supposed to take in a string and split it into an array of diffrent lines.The format of the string is shown bellow (it has no explicit \n, just a new line created through the enter key). How should I achieve my desired outcome?

```
    2PT 3PT FTM FTA PTS REB AST BLK STL GP
Mehmet Acikel Senior    15  —   4   9   34  —   —   —   —   10
Justin Baker Senior —   6   5   8   23  —   —   —   —   8
Saul Brauns Junior  3   3   4   4   19  6   1   1   —   11
Benjamin Derman Sophomore   1   1   —   —   5   1   —   —   1   3
Ayotunde Fagbemi Sophomore  44  —   4   13  92  16  —   1   3   14
Andrew Garrod Sophomore 1   —   —   1   2   3   —   —   —   4
Evan Oliver Junior  7   3   8   13  29  9   3   —   —   12
Shane Sampson Sophomore —   4   2   4   14  3   1   —   1   4
Zach Shirodkar  22  32  11  15  154 5   4   —   3   13
Nicholas Sikellis Senior    6   —   4   5   16  8   1   —   —   7
Jaden Simon Junior  32  28  12  16  157 8   2   —   4   14
Isaac Stein Junior • G  18  4   15  26  63  5   5   —   6   13
Dylan Wapner Senior • G 31  10  30  48  114 7   10  —   11  14
Total:  180 91  99  162 722 71  27  2   29  127
```

```
//Initialize String

const textAreaElement = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
const homeData = textAreaElement.value;

//Attempt to split String at new line, (unsuccessful as the format desired does not have //an explicit new line token such as \n)

var lines = homeData.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);

//Log first line to test if split worked correctly 

console.log(lines[0]);
```

Comment: so, you don't get an error like `SyntaxError: \"\" string literal contains an unescaped line break` - use `\`` instead of `"` then you can use your split as is

Comment: Why do you think the data doesn't have `\n` in it? That's what you get when you type the Enter key in a textarea.

Comment: you need to use '`' instead of '"' for multi-lines string

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman The question has been edited, it doesn't contain a string literal any more.

Comment: Your code works as written: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/r4jv2w0z/

Comment: @Barmar i agree with you, the code is working good, as per the edit

Answer (score 0):

You can't split a string using a regExp to match `\r\n`, or `\r`, or `n`, and have the split operation append to or replace the matched substring with a new line that is included in output at the same time.

1. While you can put capturing groups in a regExp to make `split` insert the captured value in the output array, *it inserts them as new entries*, so

   ```
    "line1\nline2\n".split(/(\n)/g);  // would produce
    ["line1, "\n", "line2", "\n"]  // not the desired format
   ```
2. If the input text contains carriage returns used for new lines, there are no `\n` characters in the text string to begin with - they need to be added as part of formatting.

---

An example of how to split and format the text:

```js
"use strict";
const text = "line1\r\nline2\rline3\n";
const array = text.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/g);
if( array.length && !array[array.length-1]) {
  array.pop();
}
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
  array[i] = array[i] + '\n';
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

**Note** If you process array entries after the split operation it may be beneficial to add the new line separators afterwards.